# Promise.all is not working but nesting promises is

Tags: angularjs

In my directive I have something that looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(s1, s2, s3) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        link: function($scope,) {
            s1.then(function(data) {
                $scope.s1 = data;
                s2.then(function(data) {
                    $scope.s2 = data;
                    s3.then(function(data) {
                        $scope.s3 = data;
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        templateUrl: '/static/partials/some-file.html'
    }
});
```

The above code works and functions the way I want it to. However, it looks ugly and I rather do something cleaner. When I try to use `Promise.all([s1, s2, s3]` then store the results into `$scope` and render it into `some-file.html`, it doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? How have you tried using `Promise.all`? You should probably use `$q.all` instead so that angular knows when the promises resolve

Comment: I've used

    Promise.all([s1, s2, s3]).then(function(response) {
       $scope.s1 = s1;
       $scope.s2 = s2; 
       $scope.s3 = s3;
    });

EDIT: accidentally press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment shows the issue:

```
Promise.all([s1, s2, s3])
.then(function(response) { 
  $scope.s1 = s1; 
  $scope.s2 = s2; 
  $scope.s3 = s3; 
});
```

The response is how it should be mapped:

```
Promise.all([s1, s2, s3])
.then(function(response) { 
  $scope.s1 = response[0]; 
  $scope.s2 = response[1]; 
  $scope.s3 = response[2]; 
});
```

I would however suggest using `$q.all` as rob suggests.